# User with dba privs can't login to APEX, but can from SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle 11gR2 XE. A user with dba privileges can't log in to the APEX interface, but can from the command line with `sqlplus`.

I just created user:

```
CREATE ROLE administrators;
GRANT dba TO administrators;
CREATE USER superuser IDENTIFIED BY "root";
GRANT administrators TO superuser;
```

If I run `cmd`, type `sqlplus` and log in with "superuser", I get access.

But the web interface (APEX) denies access with an "invalid credentials" error message.

What do I need to do to be able to log in on the APEX interface?

Answer (score 2):

The APEX administrator accounts are not linked to a database schema. Reciprocally, creating a database schema won't create an APEX account.

You'll have to create the administrator account via the web interface.

1. [Connect to the administration page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11947/start.htm#BABJDFIF):

   > - If your setup uses the embedded PL/SQL gateway, go to:
   >
   >   ```
   >   http://hostname:port/apex/apex_admin
   >   ```
   > - If your setup uses Apache and mod_plsql, go to:
   >
   >   ```
   >   http://hostname:port/pls/apex/apex_admin
   >   ```

   Then On the Login page:

   > - In Username, enter admin.
   > - In Password, enter the Oracle Application Express administrator account password you specified when you installed Oracle Application Express.
2. There are [three levels of administration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12512/adm_roles.htm#BABHADJI), decide which type you want to create:

   > - **Developers** create and edit applications.
   > - **Workspace administrators** are developers who also perform administrator tasks specific to their workspace such as managing user accounts, monitoring workspace activity, and viewing log files. See "Workspace and Application Administration".
   > - **Oracle Application Express administrators** are superusers that manage the entire hosted instance using the Oracle Application Express Administration Services application.

I suppose you want to create an APEX administrator account. They are workspace administrator of the special workspace "Administration" that you can create following the standard [APEX account creation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12512/aadm_users.htm#BABGEAJE).

Comment: So Apex users are different from db system users (ones logging by sqlplus)?

Comment: Apex users and database schemas (users) are totally disjoint.